# Как скопировать свойства одного объекта в другой?

Tags: объекты, javascript

Реализовать функцию `extend(obj1, obj2)`, которая скопирует свойства из объекта obj2 в объект obj1. Функция должна возвращать obj1. Значения одинаковых ключей должны перетирать оригинальные. Пример:

```
extend({foo: 'bar', baz: 1}, {foo: true, zoop: 0}); // {foo: true, baz: 1, zoop: 0}
```

Думал сделать через какой-то метод, но не нашел...
Читал-читал про методы, но нигде не увидел, как скопировать свойства одного в другой.

Comment: @Виталина ♦  @Expert ♦♦  полный дубль [вопроса](http://hashcode.ru/questions/377823/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9). Объединить бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для глубокого копирования недостаточно передать в свойство весь вложенный объект - это будет ссылка на него, а не новый объект, необходимо пройтись по каждому элементу.

```js
function extend(obj1, obj2){
    function copyObject(obj){
        var result = {};
        for (key in obj) {
            if(typeof(obj[key]) != 'object'){
                result[key] = obj[key];
            }
            else {
                result[key] = copyObject(obj[key])
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    for (key in obj2){
        if(typeof(obj2[key]) != 'object'){
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
        else {
            obj1[key] = copyObject(obj2[key]);
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь приведен код для копирования объекта со всеми свойствами. Внимание: если в свойстве будет объект, то его свойства не будут скопированы, для "глубокого" копирования нужно применять рекурсию:

```
function extend(obj1, obj2){
    for (key in obj2){
      obj1[key]=obj2[key];
    }
    return obj1;
}
```

Comment: Да мне не нужно объекта копировать. Нужно свойство одного объекта скопировать в другой обьект.

Comment: Приведенный мною код полностью соответствует условию задачи, проверьте.

Answer (score 1):

См., например, [как это сделано](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) (метод `extend()`) в библиотеке Underscore:

```
  _.extend = function(obj) {
    if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
    var source, prop;
    for (var i = 1, length = arguments.length; i < length; i++) {
      source = arguments[i];
      for (prop in source) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(source, prop)) {
            obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
  };
```